# PHP Add if statement html variable

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I am trying to add if statemenet into $html variable. But it see php as a html tag. how can add this statement. Thanks

```
$html = '

    <?php if (x=y):?>

    <div>
          Help me )
    </div>

    <?php endif ?> 
';
```

Comment: What are you trying to solve by doing this? Maybe we can find a better way.

Comment: The if statement is incorrect - should be if( x == y )....

Comment: `x` and `y` are constants, right?

Comment: Oh come on with the duplicate. The title is so much different there was no way to find it for inexperienced stack users.

Comment: But how i can add into $html = ''; atribute this if statement. into $html i have anouther div to i cant delete all of them

Comment: The codde is different and long. I can add valu like ' . $text . ' it works but with if it is not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following

```
$html = '';

if(x==y):
    $html .= '<div> Help me )</div>';
endif;
```

You can do without closing php tags.

**Edited**

After @MichałSkrzypek comment I have edited and fix mistake in `if statement`

Comment: there is an error in if statement. should be ==

Comment: @MichałSkrzypek Thank you so much for letting me know. Unfortunately I didn;t notice

Comment: But how i can add into $html = ''; atribute this if statement. into $html i have anouther div to i cant delete all of them

Comment: As you asked in the question that you wanted to add something in `$html = '';` so above code will be add div only when `if statement` will be true

Comment: I understand but how i can choose the right place? if i wont to add that dive after selected div? in $html

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is impossible. If you would want to echo the var, you would put `<?php` inside of `<?php`, which must result in an error. Only add

```
    <div>
          Help me )
    </div>
```

to a var.

Comment: "impossible" is a rather big word.

Comment: But accurate. I edited the post, because it didn't show my whole answer. Now there is an explanation why it is not possible.

Comment: If you rework a bit OP's code (remove php tags and use `echo` around the `div`) I'm pretty sure you can pass it to `eval`. Not wise but definitely possible.

Comment: If you rework it, it's possible. If you change code to working, it will work. Still impossible if you don't.